# Group Concat with JOIN with data in first table is NULL in second

Tags: magento-1.9, database, query

I have a query which joins two table. Invoice table and comments table.
But there are instances that an invoice has no equivalent row in Comments table.

My query returns those who has both, Example is My Invoice ID 1 has two rows in Comments table thus returning concatenated 2 rows in Comment table and joins it to my invoice table, but what if I also want to display those who has no comments in Comments table.

Sample is below

```
Table 1 (INVOICE TABLE)      TABLE 2 (COMMENTS TABLE)

ID   NAME                      ID  COMMENTS
1    MYINVOCIE                 1   YEAH
2    MY OTHER INVOICE          1   ALRIGHT
```

MY QUERY WILL RETURN IT AS

```
TABLE WITH CONCAT AND JOINED
ID    NAME         COMMENTS
1    MY INVOICE    YEAH|ALRIGHT
```

But it does not show the 2 because in my query it checks if the ID has an equal ID on the table 2.
I want my result to be like

```
TABLE I WANT TO HAVE AS A RESULT
ID       NAME             COMMENT
1      MY INVOICE         YEAH|ALRIGHT
2      MY OTHER INVOICE   NULL
```

Here's my QUERY

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, 
(
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(comment SEPARATOR '|' ) 
  FROM mgmx_sales_flat_invoice_comment a WHERE a.parent_id = 
  main_table.entity_id 
  group by parent_id
) AS `comment` 
FROM `mgmx_sales_flat_invoice_grid` AS `main_table`
INNER JOIN `mgmx_sales_flat_invoice_comment` AS `a` 
ON a.parent_id = main_table.entity_id  
GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It has something to do with joining.

I rewrite my query to this.

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, 
(
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(comment SEPARATOR '|' ) 
 FROM mgmx_sales_flat_invoice_comment a WHERE a.parent_id = 
 main_table.entity_id 
 group by parent_id
) AS `comment` 
FROM `mgmx_sales_flat_invoice_grid` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `mgmx_sales_flat_invoice_comment` AS `a` 
ON a.parent_id = main_table.entity_id  
 GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`
```